# MariaDB won't start after upgrade to 10.2 on Centos 7

Tags: centos, mariadb

I am new to Linux.
I upgraded MariaDB to version 10.2.33 today and the service refuses to start:

```
mariadb.service - MariaDB 10.2.33 database server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/mariadb.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
  Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/mariadb.service.d
           └─migrated-from-my.cnf-settings.conf
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2020-09-09 17:21:29 IST; 36min ago
     Docs: man:mysqld(8)
           https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/systemd/
  Process: 4577 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld $MYSQLD_OPTS --basedir=/usr $_WSREP_NEW_CLUSTER $_WSREP_START_POSITION (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 4546 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c [ ! -e /usr/bin/galera_recovery ] && VAR= ||   VAR=`cd /usr/bin/..; /usr/bin/galera_recovery`; [ $? -eq 0 ]   && systemctl set-environment _WSREP_START_POSITION=$VAR || exit 1 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 4545 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c systemctl unset-environment _WSREP_START_POSITION (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 4577 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Status: "MariaDB server is down"

Sep 09 17:21:26 kinintapp01.server.ie systemd[1]: Starting MariaDB 10.2.33 database server...
Sep 09 17:21:26 kinintapp01.server.ie mysqld[4577]: 2020-09-09 17:21:26 140201819867328 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 10.2.33-MariaDB) starting as process 4577 ...
Sep 09 17:21:26 kinintapp01.server.ie mysqld[4577]: 2020-09-09 17:21:26 140201819867328 [Warning] Could not increase number of max_open_files to more than 16384 (request: 32184)
Sep 09 17:21:29 kinintapp01.server.ie systemd[1]: mariadb.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Sep 09 17:21:29 kinintapp01.server.ie systemd[1]: Failed to start MariaDB 10.2.33 database server.
Sep 09 17:21:29 kinintapp01.server.ie systemd[1]: Unit mariadb.service entered failed state.
Sep 09 17:21:29 kinintapp01.server.ie systemd[1]: mariadb.service failed.
```

On examining the error logs:

```
2020-09-09 16:11:53 139670995248896 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (initiated by: unknown): Normal shutdown
2020-09-09 16:11:53 139670995248896 [Note] Event Scheduler: Purging the queue. 0 events
2020-09-09 16:11:53 139671036217088 [Note] InnoDB: FTS optimize thread exiting.
2020-09-09 16:11:53 139670995248896 [Note] InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
2020-09-09 16:11:53 139670918784768 [Note] InnoDB: Dumping buffer pool(s) to /var/lib/mysql/ib_buffer_pool
2020-09-09 16:11:53 139670918784768 [Note] InnoDB: Instance 0, restricted to 2047 pages due to innodb_buf_pool_dump_pct=25
2020-09-09 16:11:53 139670918784768 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) dump completed at 200909 16:11:53
2020-09-09 16:11:54 139670995248896 [Note] InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 3943889843
2020-09-09 16:11:54 139670995248896 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "ibtmp1"
200909 16:11:54 [ERROR] mysqld got signal 7 ;
This could be because you hit a bug. It is also possible that this binary
or one of the libraries it was linked against is corrupt, improperly built,
or misconfigured. This error can also be caused by malfunctioning hardware.

To report this bug, see https://mariadb.com/kb/en/reporting-bugs

We will try our best to scrape up some info that will hopefully help
diagnose the problem, but since we have already crashed,
something is definitely wrong and this may fail.

Server version: 10.2.24-MariaDB
key_buffer_size=134217728
read_buffer_size=131072
max_used_connections=75
max_threads=153
thread_count=0
It is possible that mysqld could use up to
key_buffer_size + (read_buffer_size + sort_buffer_size)*max_threads = 467240 K  bytes of memory
Hope that's ok; if not, decrease some variables in the equation.

Thread pointer: 0x0
Attempting backtrace. You can use the following information to find out
where mysqld died. If you see no messages after this, something went
terribly wrong...
stack_bottom = 0x0 thread_stack 0x49000
/usr/sbin/mysqld(my_print_stacktrace+0x2e)[0x55c5caacc58e]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(handle_fatal_signal+0x30d)[0x55c5ca55821d]
:0(__ftrylockfile)[0x7f07dae405d0]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_ZN11TC_LOG_MMAP5closeEv+0xfb)[0x55c5ca62d7db]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x44a294)[0x55c5ca329294]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z10unireg_endv+0x3b)[0x55c5ca32ae4b]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x45072c)[0x55c5ca32f72c]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(kill_server_thread+0xe)[0x55c5ca32f7be]
:0(__nptl_deallocate_tsd)[0x7f07dae38dd5]
/lib64/libc.so.6(clone+0x6d)[0x7f07d91daead]
The manual page at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/crashing.html contains
information that should help you find out what is causing the crash.
Writing a core file...
Working directory at /var/lib/mysql
Resource Limits:
Limit                     Soft Limit           Hard Limit           Units
Max cpu time              unlimited            unlimited            seconds
Max file size             unlimited            unlimited            bytes
Max data size             unlimited            unlimited            bytes
Max stack size            8388608              unlimited            bytes
Max core file size        0                    unlimited            bytes
Max resident set          unlimited            unlimited            bytes
Max processes             15681                15681                processes
Max open files            16364                16364                files
Max locked memory         65536                65536                bytes
Max address space         unlimited            unlimited            bytes
Max file locks            unlimited            unlimited            locks
Max pending signals       15681                15681                signals
Max msgqueue size         819200               819200               bytes
Max nice priority         0                    0
Max realtime priority     0                    0
Max realtime timeout      unlimited            unlimited            us
Core pattern: core

2020-09-09 16:11:54 139920515954880 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2020-09-09 16:11:54 139920515954880 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2020-09-09 16:11:54 139920515954880 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.7
2020-09-09 16:11:54 139920515954880 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2020-09-09 16:11:54 139920515954880 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2020-09-09 16:11:54 139920515954880 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2020-09-09 16:11:54 139920515954880 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 128M, instances = 1, chunk size = 128M
2020-09-09 16:11:54 139920515954880 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2020-09-09 16:11:54 139919955982080 [Note] InnoDB: If the mysqld execution user is authorized, page cleaner thread priority can be changed. See the man page of setpriority().
2020-09-09 16:11:54 139920515954880 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2020-09-09 16:11:54 139920515954880 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2020-09-09 16:11:54 139920515954880 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2020-09-09 16:11:54 139920515954880 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file './ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2020-09-09 16:11:54 139920515954880 [Note] InnoDB: File './ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2020-09-09 16:11:54 139920515954880 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2020-09-09 16:11:54 139920515954880 [Note] InnoDB: 5.7.31 started; log sequence number 3943889843
2020-09-09 16:11:54 139919791990528 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from /var/lib/mysql/ib_buffer_pool
2020-09-09 16:11:54 139920515954880 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2020-09-09 16:11:54 139920515954880 [Note] Recovering after a crash using tc.log
2020-09-09 16:11:54 139920515954880 [ERROR] Can't init tc log
2020-09-09 16:11:54 139920515954880 [ERROR] Aborting

2020-09-09 17:21:26 140201819867328 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2020-09-09 17:21:26 140201819867328 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2020-09-09 17:21:26 140201819867328 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.7
2020-09-09 17:21:26 140201819867328 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2020-09-09 17:21:26 140201819867328 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2020-09-09 17:21:26 140201819867328 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2020-09-09 17:21:26 140201819867328 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 128M, instances = 1, chunk size = 128M
2020-09-09 17:21:26 140201819867328 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2020-09-09 17:21:26 140201259554560 [Note] InnoDB: If the mysqld execution user is authorized, page cleaner thread priority can be changed. See the man page of setpriority().
2020-09-09 17:21:26 140201819867328 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2020-09-09 17:21:26 140201819867328 [ERROR] InnoDB: Operating system error number 2 in a file operation.
2020-09-09 17:21:26 140201819867328 [ERROR] InnoDB: The error means the system cannot find the path specified.
2020-09-09 17:21:26 140201819867328 [ERROR] InnoDB: If you are installing InnoDB, remember that you must create directories yourself, InnoDB does not create them.
2020-09-09 17:21:26 140201819867328 [ERROR] InnoDB: Cannot open datafile for read-only: './khtint/wp_posts.ibd' OS error: 71
2020-09-09 17:21:26 140201819867328 [ERROR] InnoDB: Operating system error number 2 in a file operation.
2020-09-09 17:21:26 140201819867328 [ERROR] InnoDB: The error means the system cannot find the path specified.
2020-09-09 17:21:26 140201819867328 [ERROR] InnoDB: If you are installing InnoDB, remember that you must create directories yourself, InnoDB does not create them.
2020-09-09 17:21:26 140201819867328 [ERROR] InnoDB: Could not find a valid tablespace file for `khtint/wp_posts`. Please refer to https://mariadb.com/kb/en/innodb-data-dictionary-troubleshooting/ for how to resolve the issue.
2020-09-09 17:21:26 140201819867328 [Warning] InnoDB: Ignoring tablespace for `khtint`.`wp_posts` because it could not be opened.
2020-09-09 17:21:26 140201819867328 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2020-09-09 17:21:26 140201819867328 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2020-09-09 17:21:26 140201819867328 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file './ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2020-09-09 17:21:26 140201819867328 [Note] InnoDB: File './ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2020-09-09 17:21:26 140201819867328 [Note] InnoDB: 5.7.31 started; log sequence number 3943890087
2020-09-09 17:21:26 140200818767616 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from /var/lib/mysql/ib_buffer_pool
2020-09-09 17:21:26 140200818767616 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 200909 17:21:26
2020-09-09 17:21:26 140201819867328 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2020-09-09 17:21:26 140201819867328 [Note] Recovering after a crash using tc.log
2020-09-09 17:21:26 140201819867328 [ERROR] Can't init tc log
2020-09-09 17:21:26 140201819867328 [ERROR] Aborting
2020-09-09 17:21:26 140201819867328 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2020-09-09 17:21:26 140201819867328 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2020-09-09 17:21:26 140201819867328 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.7
2020-09-09 17:21:26 140201819867328 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2020-09-09 17:21:26 140201819867328 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2020-09-09 17:21:26 140201819867328 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2020-09-09 17:21:26 140201819867328 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 128M, instances = 1, chunk size = 128M
2020-09-09 17:21:26 140201819867328 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2020-09-09 17:21:26 140201259554560 [Note] InnoDB: If the mysqld execution user is authorized, page cleaner thread priority can be changed. See the man page of setpriority().
2020-09-09 17:21:26 140201819867328 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2020-09-09 17:21:26 140201819867328 [ERROR] InnoDB: Operating system error number 2 in a file operation.
2020-09-09 17:21:26 140201819867328 [ERROR] InnoDB: The error means the system cannot find the path specified.
2020-09-09 17:21:26 140201819867328 [ERROR] InnoDB: If you are installing InnoDB, remember that you must create directories yourself, InnoDB does not create them.
2020-09-09 17:21:26 140201819867328 [ERROR] InnoDB: Cannot open datafile for read-only: './khtint/wp_posts.ibd' OS error: 71
2020-09-09 17:21:26 140201819867328 [ERROR] InnoDB: Operating system error number 2 in a file operation.
2020-09-09 17:21:26 140201819867328 [ERROR] InnoDB: The error means the system cannot find the path specified.
2020-09-09 17:21:26 140201819867328 [ERROR] InnoDB: If you are installing InnoDB, remember that you must create directories yourself, InnoDB does not create them.
2020-09-09 17:21:26 140201819867328 [ERROR] InnoDB: Could not find a valid tablespace file for `khtint/wp_posts`. Please refer to https://mariadb.com/kb/en/innodb-data-dictionary-troubleshooting/ for how to resolve the issue.
2020-09-09 17:21:26 140201819867328 [Warning] InnoDB: Ignoring tablespace for `khtint`.`wp_posts` because it could not be opened.
2020-09-09 17:21:26 140201819867328 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2020-09-09 17:21:26 140201819867328 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2020-09-09 17:21:26 140201819867328 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file './ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2020-09-09 17:21:26 140201819867328 [Note] InnoDB: File './ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2020-09-09 17:21:26 140201819867328 [Note] InnoDB: 5.7.31 started; log sequence number 3943890087
2020-09-09 17:21:26 140200818767616 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from /var/lib/mysql/ib_buffer_pool
2020-09-09 17:21:26 140200818767616 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 200909 17:21:26
2020-09-09 17:21:26 140201819867328 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2020-09-09 17:21:26 140201819867328 [Note] Recovering after a crash using tc.log
2020-09-09 17:21:26 140201819867328 [ERROR] Can't init tc log
2020-09-09 17:21:26 140201819867328 [ERROR] Aborting

2020-09-09 17:21:26 140201819867328 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2020-09-09 17:21:26 140201819867328 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2020-09-09 17:21:26 140201819867328 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.7
2020-09-09 17:21:26 140201819867328 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2020-09-09 17:21:26 140201819867328 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2020-09-09 17:21:26 140201819867328 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2020-09-09 17:21:26 140201819867328 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 128M, instances = 1, chunk size = 128M
2020-09-09 17:21:26 140201819867328 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2020-09-09 17:21:26 140201259554560 [Note] InnoDB: If the mysqld execution user is authorized, page cleaner thread priority can be changed. See the man page of setpriority().
2020-09-09 17:21:26 140201819867328 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2020-09-09 17:21:26 140201819867328 [ERROR] InnoDB: Operating system error number 2 in a file operation.
2020-09-09 17:21:26 140201819867328 [ERROR] InnoDB: The error means the system cannot find the path specified.
2020-09-09 17:21:26 140201819867328 [ERROR] InnoDB: If you are installing InnoDB, remember that you must create directories yourself, InnoDB does not create them.
2020-09-09 17:21:26 140201819867328 [ERROR] InnoDB: Cannot open datafile for read-only: './khtint/wp_posts.ibd' OS error: 71
2020-09-09 17:21:26 140201819867328 [ERROR] InnoDB: Operating system error number 2 in a file operation.
2020-09-09 17:21:26 140201819867328 [ERROR] InnoDB: The error means the system cannot find the path specified.
2020-09-09 17:21:26 140201819867328 [ERROR] InnoDB: If you are installing InnoDB, remember that you must create directories yourself, InnoDB does not create them.
2020-09-09 17:21:26 140201819867328 [ERROR] InnoDB: Could not find a valid tablespace file for `khtint/wp_posts`. Please refer to https://mariadb.com/kb/en/innodb-data-dictionary-troubleshooting/ for how to resolve the issue.
2020-09-09 17:21:26 140201819867328 [Warning] InnoDB: Ignoring tablespace for `khtint`.`wp_posts` because it could not be opened.
2020-09-09 17:21:26 140201819867328 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2020-09-09 17:21:26 140201819867328 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2020-09-09 17:21:26 140201819867328 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file './ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2020-09-09 17:21:26 140201819867328 [Note] InnoDB: File './ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2020-09-09 17:21:26 140201819867328 [Note] InnoDB: 5.7.31 started; log sequence number 3943890087
2020-09-09 17:21:26 140200818767616 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from /var/lib/mysql/ib_buffer_pool
2020-09-09 17:21:26 140200818767616 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 200909 17:21:26
2020-09-09 17:21:26 140201819867328 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2020-09-09 17:21:26 140201819867328 [Note] Recovering after a crash using tc.log
2020-09-09 17:21:26 140201819867328 [ERROR] Can't init tc log
2020-09-09 17:21:26 140201819867328 [ERROR] Aborting
```

My mysqld options are as follows:

> --port=3306 --socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock --datadir=/var/lib/mysql --log-error=/var/log/mariadb/mariadb.log --max_allowed_packet=50M --innodb_log_file_size=100M

I performed the same upgrade on another server with no issues but am at a loss as to how to resolve this as don't seem to be able to downgrade.
I would appreciate any tips on how to resolve.

Answer (score 1):

Issue was resolved by moving log file to backup:

```
mv /var/lib/mysql/tc.log /var/lib/mysql/tc.log.bak
```

Comment: Thanks @BGreene it works for me..